# Material table design is messed up HOW TO FIX IT

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have implemented material table in my react project, but the design is messed up for some reason

[image]

and here is my implementation:

```
<MaterialTable
      options={{
        tableLayout: "auto",
        debounceInterval: 700,
        padding: "dense",
      }}
      title="Wasfa Recipes"
      columns={columns}
      data={(query) =>
        new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          console.log("QUERY: ", query);
          const res = await getWasfaRecipes(
            query.pageSize,
            query.page,
            token
          );
          console.log("RES: ", res);
          resolve({
            data: res.recipes,
            page: res.page,
            totalCount: res.totalCount,
          });
        })
      }
    />
```

Comment: I don't see anything else messed up than the missing icons for the buttons.

Comment: also the search